# HttpUrlConnection Forbidden access to Google Shortener URL

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have implemented a class to get a short url from a long url:

```
public class URLShortener {
private final static String TAG = "URLShortener";
private final static String ADDRESS = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=API_KEY";

static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

private String longUrl;

public URLShortener(String longUrl) {
    this.longUrl = longUrl;
}

//public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String address,String longUrl) {
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl() {

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        //Define connection


        url = new URL(URLShortener.ADDRESS);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");


        //Define JSONObject
        JSONObject dataSend = new JSONObject();
        Log.d(TAG, "longURL: " + URLEncoder.encode(this.longUrl, "UTF-8"));
        dataSend.put("longURL",  URLEncoder.encode(this.longUrl, "UTF-8"));

        //Send data
        OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(dataSend.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Data send");
        Log.d(TAG, "ResponseCode: " + String.valueOf(urlConnection.getResponseCode()));

        //Display what returns POST request

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if(HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));

            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            br.close();

            //System.out.println(""+sb.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "sb: " + sb.toString());

        }else{
            //System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "urlConnection.getResponseMessage(): " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        }

        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);

        // Parse the String to a JSON Object
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "UnsuppoertedEncodingException: " + e.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Error JSONException: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return JSON Object
    return jObj;

}
}
```

When I call the method getJSONFromUrl I've got always the same result `ResponseCode = 403 (Forbidden)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It maybe easier to use  an OAuth token which goes in the Authorization header: have a look at the OAuth 2.0 setup: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

Comment: Also - does the API key need to be urlencoded?

Comment: Hi Schoenobates!!! I have encoded the url with the APIKey and I get the next error: 

06-02 18:22:02.279: W/System.err(3928): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Furlshortener%2Fv1%2Furl%3Fkey%3DAIzaSyBPt4KGB8dZ8JdJBWR2fzm9p7KgQ1lhwSw

Comment: Hey José - I meant just the key, but from the looks of things the key wouldn't need it ... what happens if you try this from curl: curl -v "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyBPt4KGB8dZ8JdJBWR2fzm9p7KgQ1lhwSw"   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'

Comment: Hi Schoenobates. Excuse me, but I don't understand what you mean :((( Maybe is my fault because I have spent so many time with these problem and I'm tired :((( I'm trying to find an example to do this with OAuth 2.0 but I don't find anything ... :(

Comment: Try using CURL to test the URL first and see if there's any problem there - the curl command to use is this: curl -v "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyBPt4KGB8dZ8JdJBWR2fzm9p7KgQ1lhwSw"   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'

Comment: I have remove the encode url and the key and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Ok, I don't know about CURL ... I'm going to try it

Comment: I've got the next error: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}

Comment: Ok, I'l try to do it again without APIKEY and I've got a 403 error: 

curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url \
>   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>   -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}